# Why dereference typecasted pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I have seen the following technique quite a lot, why is the following integer casted into an integer pointer and then dereferenced?

```
#define A (*(int *) 5)
```

What is the reason of doing it like that instead of simply writing

```
#define A 5
```

Comment: They are totally different things. The first one reads an integer at memory location 5. The second one is just a literal 5.

Comment: In the first, attempting to print `A` will likely Segfault as address `5` is near the bottom of the system-reserved memory pool. (unless you are on an embedded system or microcontroller -- then see the data-sheet)

Comment: Detailed explanation here: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/questions/276290).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Most systems do not even have thew concept of segfault.

Comment: @Lundin Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @12431234123412341234123,  Actually a `seg fault` results from the executable accessing memory that it does not own.   Almost all CPUs, with a memory controller , have the concept of a seg fault,

Comment: @user3629249 I said most systems, not CPUs. Most processors and microcontrollers do not have a MMU, so they can not have the concept of a segfault.

Comment: accessing a memory address that is not populated with hardware will also cause a seg fault event

Answer (score 2):

```
#define A (*(int *) 5)
```

Is declaring something like a variable. Using that "variable", you can easily access to the address (conversion from integer to pointer is implementation-defined, but typically the integer value should be used as address, I guess) using `A`. This will be useful, for example, in embedded environments or creating operating system.

In the other hand,

```
#define A 5
```

is simply defining an integer constant. In this case you cannot assign anything to `A` like `A = 42;`.

Comment: In the first case, #define A (*(int *) 5) you can't assign A = 42 as well...

Comment: @PieterDubbel I think you can.

Comment: MikeCAT, I think mentioning the concept of memory mapped peripheral registgers (part of embedded concepts) would improve the plausibility of why anybody could expect to find something useful at an "arbitrary address". Maybe along with a hint that "5" is probably a over-simplified example. I am used to addresses in the range of 0xFFFFnnnn being used.

Comment: @PieterDubbel it depends on your hardware. If your program is running on a desktop computer, `(*(int *) 5) = 42;` will most likely crash. If your program runs on a microcontroller, it can work and it can make sense, but it entirely depends on the microcontroller.

Comment: @Yunnosch There are real world examples that use that range for SFR. A AT90CAN32 has `PORTB` at address 5.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Ah, good to know. Thanks. Nevertheless, that also shows, that the MMPR concept is a helpful example.

Comment: 5 was indeed a random number that I've chosen, thanks all of you!

Comment: Most low end microcontrollers have valid addresses from 0x0 and upwards. Back in the days, a lot of them utilized something called "zero page RAM", which meant that items stored at 8 bit addresses from 0x0 to 0xFF could get accessed faster than other data. So it is common to place for example memory-mapped GPIO hardware registers there. Most MCUs at least on the Motorola side of things do this.

Comment: @user253751 that's more or less what I have written. But it still depends on the embedded system we're talking about.